# square root of sum of squares approximated by sum times square root of 2 over pi

Tags: approximation

I found somebody using the following approximation for $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$:

$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \approx (x+y) \sqrt{2/\pi},$

where $x$ and $y$ are positive numbers smaller than 1. 
It appears in this context:

[http://www.cepii.fr/CEPII/en/publications/wp/abstract.asp?NoDoc=2726; p.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBWN2.png)

So $x^2$ and $y^2$ are variances of a random value which describes the reporting error in trade data (assumed to be log-normally distributed).

What's the rationale for this approximation?

I tried several values for $x$ and $y$ and the approximation isn't too bad. E.g. $x=0.5$ and $y=0.3$ yields 0.64 instead of 0.58, and even for $x=0.9$ and $y=0.1$, the error is still acceptable (0.80 instead of 0.91). In most practical cases, we expect $x$ and $y$ to be of somewhat similar size (let's say a maximum ratio $x/y$ of 2).

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean?  In what range is this meant to be useful?  At $(1,1)$ you get $2\approx 1.59577$, not very good.  If $x,y$ are large it gets much worse.  If $x,y<0$ then it is terrible.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As it stands, it really doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: In which context did you see this approximation ?

Comment: I believe the author meant **rationale**. Seems like a simple error :)

Comment: This approximation certainly doesn't work very well as an approximation. For example, suppose you chose some x and some y that makes $x^2 + y^2 = a$, [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4nloadevtq) illustrates how good the approximation is. I'd say it's pretty bad except when a is almost 1.

Comment: Working backwards a bit, $x+y=\sqrt{(x+y)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+2xy+y^2}$. So your question amounts to justifying approximating $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+2xy+y^2}$ by $\frac{2}{\pi}$ over some region. Yet this function is clearly quite far from being constant even on a region like $[0,1]^2$.